# How can you check profiles you have visited, photos you have seen etc in your Facebook account?

Tags: facebook, facebook-privacy

I know a certain person has access to my Facebook account.

What now came to my knowledge is that this person can somehow know even the profiles I have visited, and the photos I have looked at, and the time I did it.

I am not a Facebook pro, actually I don't even like it that much, but it bothers me to know that someone can know all that from my profile.

So, how do I do it? How do I check this information?

Comment: Is it not possible to do that, you can only modify your password to disallowed to happened again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I found out what was going on.

I did not know, but your activity log now keeps track of all you search via the search bar.
That's how the person mentioned knew whose profiles I visited etc. You just have to click in "Include Only Me Activity".

Comment: In your question you didn't mention you searched for it, just visited.

Comment: Yea, indeed I did not make the distinction, and I am sorry for it. But I did not know, at first, that only what you search is recorded.

Comment: No worries, thanks for sharing the answer, that's good to know!

Answer (score 6):

Facebook doesn't make this information available (history of profiles/photos visited). The person you mentioned probably has access to your browser history or added some logging applications on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

To investigate this you need to figure out whether  this person is aware of your Facebook activity done on computer or mobile device. If it is done on mobile device then are you using Facebook app or a browser? Always provide more technical details in order to be helped.

A. If you think your mobile device activity is only known to this person:

1. My number # 1 guess is that you have a spy app installed. It takes 5-15 min to install if this person has access to your device.  This works only if you have either iPhone or rooted Android (if that's not you case then go to #2). In this case you need to restore factory setting on your phone.
2. Check whether in any of your browsers or google apps you have someone else's account logged in. Nowadays Google provide a great tool that tracks your web and app activity.
3. Check whether you have any pairing apps installed (pairs mobile for example with iPad to store data and whatever you see on the screen of your mobile can be seen on iPad).
4. Your Facebook app logs is stored on your device and once connected to PC it can be retrieved with special apps.

B. If your PC Facebook activity is known to someone else.

1. Does this person has access to your computer? Browser history provides detailed info on which photo and what time you looked at... And even has your passwords stored..
2. Sometimes even clearing browsing history will not help, as logs can be retrieved, and not only your Facebook activity, but simply all type of activity done on your computer can be easily retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to go to your activity log then click filter option, there you will find search. When you click search you can see all the profiles you have been through, there will a delete option in the top. Click that and confirm then no one will know whose profile you go through.

Answer (score -1):

I also don't know if it's possible to know whose profile i have visited. But, you can see what keywords has been searched by your profile, this'll help if the person has visited the  profile after searching it in search bar. second thing you can do is change your password and log yourself out from all other devices,so the person you're talking about can't access your account. this you can do from privacy setting in facebook.

Answer (score -1):

You can view you "Activity Log" when you go to edit your profile. At that point you can remove anything you don't want someone to see if they access your account through your login.

Comment: The OP asked to to know where you can see visited profiles and viewed photos. This information is not available in the Activity log.